# this.props not accessible when using ApolloClient

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-boost

I am using apollo-boost and I have created an ApolloClient and I want to do some redirection after a mutation is run but I cannot access the props

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";

import "./bootstrap";
import Routes from "./RoutesComponent";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
});

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

RoutesComponent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Register from "./authenticate/register/RegisterComponent";
import Login from "./authenticate/login/LoginComponent";
import Product from "./customers/product/ProductComponent";
import AddProduct from "./customers/add-product/AddProductComponent";
import Products from "./customers/products/ProductsComponent";
import AdminProduct from "./admin/product/ProductComponent";
import AdminProducts from "./admin/products/ProductsComponent";

class RoutesComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/products/new" render={() => <AddProduct />} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
export default RoutesComponent;
```

AddProductComponent

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AddProductComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>AddProductComponent</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AddProductComponent;
```

this.props in console shows `{}`

to mitigate this I also tried using history package and it changes the url but redirection does not work

I can do the redirection using state but I would rather do it using history prop than state.

any advise on this will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is specific to react-router-dom and really has nothing to do with react-apollo. You could strip out all the apollo code and you will still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Route`'s render function takes `props` as argument and since you're not passing it, it won't be available in the component

```
<Route path="/products/new" render={() => <AddProduct />} />
```

Fixed:

```
<Route path="/products/new" component={AddProduct} />
```